# PHP - Convert binary chunks to a video file - feasible?

Tags: html, chunking

I am creating an application which requires slicing a video file (mp4 format) into chunks. Our server caps the `upload_max_filesize` at 2MB, but we have files that are hundreds of MBs in size which require uploading. So far I slice the file (into 1MB chunks) using HTML5 FileReader() then upload each chunk using ajax. (here is part of the function I have written)

```
reader.onload = function() {
    $.ajax -> send current blob to server by method POST
};

blob = window.videoFile.slice(byteStart, byteEnd);
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

Here's the question: will concatenating the files (in order) on the backend then simply setting the Content-type as so:

```
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
```

before saving the file actually reproduce the video file (i.e., perfectly not as some choppy second rate facsimile) or am I missing something here? This will require some time and the faster option may be for me to beg our server admin to alter the php.ini file to allow a much larger `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: if you sliced the file as a raw binary blob, without regard to the actual contents (e.g. analyzing the video and "slicing" at a frame boundary), then simple outputting those same chunks out in the same order would "recreate" the file on the client. The client has NO idea how/where you stored the files, and for all it knows, you could have printed out the binary data as hex numbers and have an army of monkeys waving magnets over a cat6 cable to induce the same bits.

Comment: OK...I wasn't sure. I'm just trying to see if I'm way off before trying this...thanks